# SubSite creating = File Not Found

Tags: custom-masterpage, sub-site

I manage rip-off SharePoint team site and create my custom site collection.
I can create new sites, but when I try create new subsite SharePoint gives me an error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> File Not Found.
>
> *Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
>   ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file /sites/Demo/NewSubSite/_catalogs/masterpage/EBICMaster.master does not
>   exist.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext
>   context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.CalculateFileDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData basicRequestData, ICollection&
>   directDependencies, ICollection& childDependencies)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureDependencies(HttpContext
>   context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.S...*

I use only starter master page, what I have edited. Master Pages scope is set to "site".

Elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Module Name="_catalogsmasterpage_global" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" `RootWebOnly="FALSE" Path="Files\_catalogs\masterpage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">`
<File Url="EBICMaster.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" Level="Published" Path="EBICMaster.master">
</File>
</Module></Elements>
```

Any ideas, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is this module deployed by a feature? If yes, when you go to the hive folder can you find the under TEMPLATE/Features/<FeatureName>/Files/_catalogs/masterpage/ the EBICMaster.master file? Because that's where it is looking for it. Plus, there is an unnecessary "`" sign before RootWebOnly, but probably that is only a typo here, in the question.

Comment: Yes, this module is deployed by a feature. If I navigate: "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\EBIC SPF_MasterPages\Files\_catalogs\masterpage" I can find my "EBICMaster.master".

Comment: How do you refer your master page on your page? Do you use the ~masterurl/default.master token or something else?

Comment: I use MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master", I have also tried use MasterPageFile="~masterurl/EBICMaster.master"

Comment: i faced a somewhat similar issue once, Are you using onet.xml? as far as i remember in my case i have added the masterpage url in onet.xml which is kind of fixed(hard coded), then i removed it from there deployed my master page under _catalogs/masterpage, then using UI(site action-> site settings->masterpage) set the masterpage for current site and subsite

Comment: the element.xml i used:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="CustomMaster" Url="_catalogs/masterpage">
    <File Path="CustomMaster\Custom.master" Url="Custom.master" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="ContentTypeId" Value="0x010105" />
      <Property Name="UIVersion" Value="15" />
      <Property Name="Title" Value="" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>

Comment: , One more point that i noticed that time that can give simillar error is check the top section of masterpage in the line simillar to this "<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx" %>", are you missing the '~' at the starting of src, if yes then try adding

Comment: Yes, I have ONet.xml in my web templates. I tried use similar way your Element.xml, however I had to add to module Path="Files\_catalogs\masterpage", because Visual Studio was giving error: "Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to instantiate file "EBICMaster.master" from module "_catalogsmasterpage_global": Source path "Features\EBIC SPF_MasterPages\EBICMaster.master" not found."
Also, in my master there is Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx

Comment: have you tried removing the master page url from onet.xml?

Comment: Yes, there is only feature ID now.